Not exposing IDs in a web application in case of data manipulation
Let's consider an example of a repository of books, stored in an entity "Book" in a classic MVC application. Books have non-unique names, which allows for duplicates, therefore lookup by the book name does not always provide unique selection result.
Considering an entity of Book like this:
@Entity
public class Book {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String title;
private String ISBN;

@ManyToMany // ommiting mapping details
private Set<Author> bookAuthors;

// getters, setters, etc.
}

we may have a DTOs for specific purposes, like showing data on webpage
public class BookDto {
private String title;
private String ISBN;
private Set<Author> bookAuthors;
// getters, setters, etc.
}

now correct me if I'm wrong, but the good practice is to hide IDs, meaning, in this case, to not include ID field in DTO?
If yes, then let's assume we have "list all books" page, on which we display details about book, and offer a "Edit book data" button (or delete, or whatever form of manipulating data of a single entry), which should invoke a coded functionality for the specific book. For me it would look like this (without hiding ID, as this is the only way to correctly identify non-unique titled book):
<button type="button" onclick="editBookDetails(id)">Edit book details</button>

but as mentioned before - we should hide IDs as deep as possible and avoid exposing it to the surface layers. But how should such functionality be written then? How to identify entry to edit, if not by its unique ID?
Assuming we have hidden the IDs, what is the best practice for constructing such operations? Maybe there are some approaches I am not aware of.
P.S. Yes, I know, ISBN is kinda unique. But there are multiple other examples of data that are not books, and do not have such "public" unique ID, safe to expose, like books have.

now correct me if I'm wrong, but the good practice is to hide IDs That's nonsense. What value would there be in hiding what is quite possibly the only unique identifier?

I mean, if you look at the URL bar of your question here, the ID is 78569517.

ID's are generally not supposed to be kept secret as they are (as mentioned by @ElliottFrisch) the unique identifier of a resource. What problems are you trying to solve by hiding it?

In some specific cases, it's better not to have contiguous integer IDs (1, 2, 3, 4...). Think users in a social network. You probably don't want bots to be able to crawl every single user by just sending a GET in a for-loop. In those cases, you still need an ID, but you can use something like ULID. UUID is also possible, but does not necessary have a cryptographically secure random component (i.e. it may be feasible to guess the next ID). If your data really is books, you probably don't care about that.

Hiding of IDs I think is only where there are privacy concerns.  Eg, if you were writing a banking application, incrementally generated account numbers should not be part of any URL as it would be too easy to be subject of a targeted attack (of course, banking applications should have steps to ensure only the authorised user of the account can see that page, but not all sites are so stringent). See :  https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html   , Where privacy concerns are not an issue (such as book ids) there’s no problem.

Could you encrpt/decrpt id while converting to/from DTO?

@ElliottFrisch Me being wrong in my assumption about the "good practice of hiding IDs" would explain and solve my problem :)

@jakubkrol There are some ids you should hide. Like social security number, taxpayer id or checking account number. But that's contextual. If you call the social security administration, you expect them to look you up by your ssn.

Recommend reading about domain-driven design which would probably given you an idea on "identifiers" and on which objects to use them, on which to hide them, etc. I have never heard a general "good practice to hide IDs" anywhere! For example, if you have have 2 objects - employee and employee's address (say persisted across two tables "employee" and "employee_address"), then its perhaps correct to expose employee-id publicly whereas more correct to hide the address-id (going by the concept, its wrong to say "update address abc123" but more correct to say "update address for employee pqr456").

Your Question would be improved if you explain, and link, the sources who told you that “the good practice is to hide IDs”.

I have heard of this id-hiding thing from security course vendors. I took a lot of security courses at the Fed. They seem to assume developers are too stupid to check data level authorizations for every request (there may be some books a certain user isnt allowed to check out, for example), and that having an id as a request parameter allows the user to hack the url and access any book. As long as you verify the parameter is valid for the user and action there is no harm making the id visible.

Do not eliminate IDs

the good practice is to hide IDs

As discussed in the Comments, no, your premise is incorrect. There is nothing wrong with including ID values as part of your entities.
Indeed, you must bring the ID values along if you intend further work. For example, when presenting a list of objects for the user to edit or delete, you will need the ID to distinguish which object is which. The ID after all is the identifier, identifying which object needs to be edited or deleted.
Perhaps suppress display
The user may not be particularly interested in the ID value. If so, hide the value from display in the user-interface. Behind the scenes your app still needs to identify one object from another.
For example, when listing objects in a tabular grid, with a column for every field in the class, you may choose to suppress the display of the ID column. But you still need that ID value for the editing/deleting as described above.
Sensitive identifiers
As commented by Elliott Frisch, you may have identifiers that represent sensitive information. For example government-issued identifiers such as Social Security Number (SSN) in the US.
Generally, sensitive values should not be used liberally across your app and systems. Instead of using a sensitive value as the identifier (a natural key), generate another identifier in its place (a surrogate key). This is why an employee is assigned an Employee ID upon hiring, to keep their private data locked away while providing another identifier to be used more liberally.
ISBN

ISBN is kinda unique

No, incorrect. An ISBN number is very much unique — that is its purpose, to uniquely identify every published book.
For tracking existing books, you would certainly be wise to use ISBN as the natural key of a Book entity.
The ISBN would of course not be appropriate in software to assist a publisher. A book does not get an ISBN assigned until it is formally published. So during the proposal, drafting, editing, and production phases, publishing software would need to assign a surrogate key as the identifier.
